# Deployed .war gives 404 errоr

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm tyring to deploy the following web application [link to github](https://github.com/DruidKuma/EPAM-Java-Trainings/tree/master/Task%204%20(Coffee%20Machine))
I want to use it as an example while studying java web development.
I've configurated `tomcat-users` and maven's `settings.xml` files.
 
Then I've created a .war file using this command: `jar -cvf example_project.war *` 
Finally, after starting the tomcat server, I've specified generated war file in tomcat manager:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fxRs.png)
It has appeared at the list of applications:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cnzo.png)
But the link to the main page of this application gives me 404 error:
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vQqs.png)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is this 'example-project' specified?

In https://github.com/DruidKuma/EPAM-Java-Trainings/blob/master/Task%204%20(Coffee%20Machine)/web/META-INF/context.xml,

I see root path '/Task4"

And then in https://github.com/DruidKuma/EPAM-Java-Trainings/blob/master/Task%204%20(Coffee%20Machine)/web/WEB-INF/web.xml

there are some servlets defined:
/pages/*

try accessing these:

../localhost:8080/Test4/pages

Comment: It seems that I am creating wrong .war file. At wich directory the command `jar -cvf example_project.war *` should be executed?

Comment: the project is configured to use ant, try building the war with it, 
ant build.xml